# How can I make a struct non-public and not move it from lib.rs?

Tags: rust

Consider this simple crate:

**src/lib.rs**

```
mod internal;

use internal::f;

pub(crate) struct Foo {}

pub fn g() {
    f();
}
```

**src/internal.rs**

```
use Foo;

pub fn f() -> Foo {
    unimplemented!();
}
```

I want to export only the `g` function from the crate. I also want to define `Foo` in lib.rs to simplify reading of my source code. This is an important struct for the crate, so I want to move it to the first
file that any potential reader would open.

The compiler reports:

```
error[E0446]: private type `Foo` in public interface
 --> src/internal.rs:3:1
  |
3 | / pub fn f() -> Foo {
4 | |     unimplemented!();
5 | | }
  | |_^ can't leak private type
```

How can I fix this issue? Why it is private, while it public for crate?

Comment: @ildjarn As you can see `f` is in module, not in `lib.rs`, and `lib.rs` not reexport it, so it is not visible outside of crate.

Comment: Is making `f` `pub(crate)` not sufficient..?

Comment: @ildjarn Sufficient, but that is confusing. Why `pub` is not consistent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While it's not hard to catch this case, it would actually be inconsistent for `pub` to allow private types. `pub` means that the item *may* be usable outside the crate. It doesn't matter that you aren't reexporting it, it could be that you reexport it.

The decision is local to the item declaration in order to make it easy to see whether some item could be exposed. If you are in a random file in your project, you can see whether an item is definitely not exposed by either a missing `pub` specifier or by a constraint on `pub`. This significantly increases code readability.

For more detailed information, read the relevant [RFC](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/pull/1422) or in the [tracking issue for the `private_in_public` lint](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/34537)